# jquery window top location not working in responsinator

Tags: jquery, responsive-design

I have a below code that is working in broswer without any issue. When i try to run in responsinator, after submit, I am geting page cannot be found error. Am I doing someting wrong ? Could some help on this? Thank you!

```
$(document).ready(function () {


 $('#form-signin').validate({
    rules: {
        login: {
            minlength: 3,
            maxlength: 15,
            required: true               
        },
        password: {
            minlength: 3,
            maxlength: 15,
            required: true                
        }
    },
    messages: {               //messages to appear on error
         login: {
             required:"Please Enter your user ID."                      
              },               
          password: {
              required: "Please Enter Password."                                     
              }
        },
    highlight: function (element) {
        $(element).closest('.control-group').addClass('has-error');
    },
    unhighlight: function (element) {
        $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('has-error');
    },
    sucess: function(element){
        $element.text("OK!").addClass('valid');
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {        
                  $.ajax({
                   url:"/iPay/UserValidationServlet",
                  type:"POST",
                  dataType: "json",
                  data: $('#form-signin').serialize(),

               success: function(result){
               var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( result );
                   if (obj.success) {                      
                        window.top.location = obj.redirectUrl;
                    } else {                       
                        $('#errorMessage').html(obj.message);
                    }

             }
           });
        }
});
});
```

Question number 2. Below header is shwoing fine in browser but in responsinative(verifying in dvices suc as iPad) last two columns are wraping to second row instead of adjusting on the same row.
Image sige is 315X116 pixels.

```
        <div class="page-header">         
        <div class="row">            
         <div class="col-md-1"><image src="images/NGLiPay3.png"></image></div>                          
        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-8"><%=name%></div>
            <div class="col-md-1">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info navbar-btn navbar-right">Sign Out&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-sign-out icon-1x" title="Sign Out"></button>
            </div>
        </div>      
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are likely seeing is that `Responsinator` is trying to display your content in an `iframe` and the browser is preventing that as a security measure. You can try to add your site as a 'trusted site' in the settings, or configure your browser to allow displaying unsecured content *for your site* only.

You may want to also look at other options as well for responsive testing. The following contains links, bookmarks, and browser tools that assist with showing and displaying content in different sizes: http://www.gonzoblog.nl/2012/03/21/10-testing-tools-for-responsive-web-design/

For your 2nd question I recommend starting a separate post. It's not a good idea on SO to make a post with multiple questions. It's easier to have posts with a single question that a definitive answer can be provided.